# Filter Range by specific Color Index/RGB using Worksheet.Range.Autofilter(Field,Criteria,Operator)

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, colors, filtering

I am doing some automated excel manipulation using C#. I have been having a hard time figuring out how to autofilter based on a specific color.

There is very little documentation about this type of manipulation, however I have found some VB.net and VBA code for it. I cannot seem to convert the code to C# as "RGB" is not usable as it is in VB.net and VBA (See VB.net code below).

Since there has been no answers to this questions, I want to specify the code that needs to be looked at. In Autofilter(Field,Criteria,Operator), I need to know the C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel criteria that would let me choose a color to filter.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
Excel.Worksheet xs1:
Excel.Range xRange1;
Excel.Range xRange2;
Excel.Range lastrow;
Excel.Range lastcol; 
lastrow = xs1.Rows.End[Excel.XlDirection.xlDown];
lastcol = xs1.Columns.End[Excel.XlDirection.xlToRight];   
xRange1 = xs1.Cells[2, 14];
xRange2 = xs1.Cells[lastrow.Row, 14];
```

Below selects the entire sheet and adds an autofilter(), setting it to filter for color. This works fine, but how do I pick the color I want it to filter for?

```
 xs1.Range["A1", xs1.Cells[lastrow.Row, lastcol.Column]].
 AutoFilter(14,Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic,
 Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterCellColor);
```

Here is an example of what the autofilter code would look like in VB.net. It looks very similar to this in an excel macro as well.

```
xs1.Range("A1", xs1.Cells(lastrow.Row, lastcol.Column)).
AutoFilter(Field:=14,Criteria1:=RGB(0,202,255),
Operator:=Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterCellColors)
```

Comment: if it works in VB.. could you not just add the using Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly to your header to access vb.net functionality

Comment: What does the working VB.Net statement look look?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @MethodMan That is a good idea as a final alternative, however I would like to find a C# solution as it would be most preferred. Thank you for the suggestion. We will see if anyone else can think of a solution.

Comment: @Blackwood I added it into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is how you pick the color index for any poor souls that need to figure it out themselves. I could not find this anywhere on the internet.

```
xs1.Range["A1", xs1.Cells[lastrow.Row, lastcol.Column]].
AutoFilter(14, xlBook.Colors[33], Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterCellColor);
```

The important part is the "xlBook.Colors[33]". xlBook being the Workbook. 33 being the color index.

Comment: Just use "ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red)" instead of "xlBook.Colors[33]"

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any reputation points, so I must submit an answer instead of a comment. Anyway, thank you, thank you, thank you. I have spent weeks looking for this answer and happened to search the right key words to find this post. I signed up just to upvote the answer!

My scenario is not exactly like yours, but similar enough that you led me to the solution. So, I will share what worked for me. I am trying to filter by color index using PowerShell. However, PowerShell does not allow the RGB values, as in the VB.net example above. Now, for my contribution to the answer. If you are doing this in PowerShell then it will need to look like this:

```
$xlFilterCellColor = 8
$xl = New-Object -comobject excel.application 
$xl.Visible = $true
$xl.DisplayAlerts = $False
$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open("\\path\to\file.xlsx")
$ws = $wb.worksheets.items(1)
$xlCellTypeLastCell = 11
$used = $ws.usedRange
$lastCell = $used.SpecialCells($xlCellTypeLastCell)
$range = $ws.range(A1:$lastCell)
$range.select | out-null
$range.autofilter(1,$wb.colors(6),$xlFilterCellColor)
```

The operator decimal values are listed [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839625.aspx) In the code above, I am filtering yellow colored cells. Cell index colors and values can be found [here.](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm#colorindex)